# Copy and delete .ini section in two files

Tags: powershell, scripting, ini

I have two .ini files with the same names in two different servers. The problem is one .ini file is always up to date and the other isn't. I need to copy all the sections with particular pattern from the first INI file and the same section should be deleted first and updated in the second INI file as well.

```
**[LINK.AppServer1]**
Destination=
ProgId=
Name=T1
Description=Test CR
**[LINK.AppServer2]**
Destination=
ProgId=
Name=T2
Description=Test CR2
**[LINK.User1]**
Activated=TRUE
Name=CN=PS2
Certificate=
**[LINK.User2]**
Activated=TRUE
Name=CN=PS1
Certificate=
```

I have written a script but the script is replacing all the sections after [LINK.AppServer1] instead of specific sections since there will be other sections in between.

```
$content = Get-Content "C:\Users\Test\Desktop\Section.ini"
$section1Start = $content | Where-Object { $_ -match '\[LINK.AppServer1\]'} | select -ExpandProperty ReadCount
$content | Select -Skip $section1Start | Out-File C:\Users\Test\Desktop\Section1.ini
```

So I want to know how I can copy specific section (repetitive with different numbers) from one file and delete first and replace in the second file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It might be faster to use this module on the gallery that has functions for INI files: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PsIni/2.0.0

Comment: Thank you @thomschumacher, I will give that a try! Just asking, is there not a simpler method to do this task. The scripts in the file is bit larger when I club multiple scripts to make it work. Any suggestions are welcome!